# how to compare or cluster data

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, pattern-recognition, graph-theory

I need advice regarding further steps. I have dataset about computer and their activity during 24 h for several month. I want to find best fit between peers so one computer can relay on other for some service. example data for two peers
[image]

If I create graph then it looks like

[image]

how to mesure how good they fit to each other? Some of my ideas were

- to define some "typical" computer (perfect one that will work only during work work hours) and some how to calculate "distance" from this expected behavior
- to calculate intersection area this should be their match but problem is curve shapes.
- or do some clusters with dataset to group them.

What I did is track their activity and seek for pattern matching (compare two computer and measure how often they are present and absent in a same time as measure of match) and after I group them choosing random time their availability was 54 %. I am hoping to find better solution for matching.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am hoping to find better solution for matching.

1. You can try calculating covariance or Pearson correlation coefficient between all pairs of your computers, but it will not result in matching exact values.
2. You can try calculating euclidean distance between computers. This will result is exact matching, and besides you can tell what the maximum distance can be, so this allows you to construct a metric.

Both methods are applicable to these data.

Comment: How could I calculate euclidean distance? Using uptime percentage will not produce good results.

Comment: Why do you think it will not produce good result? What is good result in your opinion?

Comment: Based on pattern match (present + absent of computers in a same time) I  made groups of computers that are similar,  hoping that they will be the most available to each other.  I made script that take random time, choose random comp and determine group. Other computer is random from same group. Then I take another random time where first computer is present and then check status of other. My script showed max of  55% match. I believe that random function can influence results but it should have minor effect.

Comment: It seems unclear what your final goal is, but as I mentioned you can legally measure the difference in computer uptimes by taking the Euclidean distance and creating a dissimilarity matrix. It can also be used in hierarchical clustering.

Comment: I have calculate simple matching coeficient that should describe pattern matching between two computers. Now I have nxn matrix that describe how one Computer match to others. I want to group them ti recognize several groups. Groups will have certain tasks for group processing and since they have similar presence pattern I believe that all comuters from one group will be present in a same time (at least majority of time) and will be able to perform task.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like a clustering task. There are manu ways. Hirarchical (aglomerative) is what I would try first. Plotting cluster profiles is second.

Comment: If I have matrix 100  x 100 (computers) and their simple matching coefficient, then this is symmetrical matrix (is this equal to Euclid distance?), and do I observe every nod as variable or, I do clusters for every computer separately? All examples that I meet first column differ from others, but in my case headers of rows and columns are the same and this confuses me.

Comment: @explorer, custom proximity metric can be used in hierarchical clustering (you just supply a function with your calculated proximity matrix). I wonder which software you prefer to make stats analysis of your data. I could give you detailed comments on R functions.

Comment: I do use R, that would be great.

Comment: @explorer, for complete details: ?hclust. **hclust(d, method = "complete", members = NULL)** d is the dissimilarity object. it can be your matrix filled with the custom metric that you built. Then you can **plot(x)**, do **cutree(tree, k )** to specify the number of clusters, and study cluster profiles.

Comment: I tried all methods and "complete" was the best one, since I reached 83% off positive matching for two random computers in two random moments. Now I want to compare this percentage with situation where I take all computers and for every computer create list of computers that a most available to that computer. example, have 2 computers one is allways on, and the other is on for 12 hours during a day. If I use this approach this computer that is allways on will be possible peer match for all computers since he is 100 % available to all. This leads to possible overload for this PC.

Comment: @explorer, the only 'no' is don't ise Ward's method with your custom metric in hierarchical clustering as Ward's only valid with Euclidean distance. You can also compare each computer profile with the cluster centers.